# How do you get the area of the current request when using MVC 2 RC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I was using MVC 1.0 RTM, and the [Haack solution](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/04/areas-in-aspnetmvc.aspx#related-results) for Areas

I just recently moved to MVC2 RC and I'm using single project areas with my controllers in separate assemblies. My problem is that in the MVC 1 solution I **ALWAYS** had "area" in my RouteData.Values collection, in MVC2 RC it doesn't exist. Do you know how to get this in MVC2 RC?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is kept in a `DataToken` for the route. Namely, `route.DataTokens["area"]`. Look at AreaHelpers.cs in the [MVC source](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=37423) for details.

By the way, when you ask a question like this, you should show the code you're using which is not working. It makes it much easier to supply an answer. Right now, I don't know if you've already tried the method above, but are making an error with it, or if you haven't discovered this yet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Craig, and sorry for not posting code, i'll try to be more specific next time!