# Determine current module's physical path

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

Inside a given Orchard module, how to determine the path to the physical directory where that module is installed?

In alternative, how to programatically determine the Module's name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve the module name twofold:

- Orchard module acts as an ASP.NET MVC 3 area, so answer to your
  second question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002751/how-do-you-get-the-area-of-the-current-request-when-using-mvc-2-rc) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723689/asp-net-mvc-get-current-area-name-in-view-or-controller). This is the better way.
- Or use reflection and get the name from the currently executing assembly, which is named like your module:

  `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name`

If you have the name, getting the physical directory is as easy as writing:

```
HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/Modules/" + moduleName)
```